# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Philosophy Stack Exchange](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Wittgenstein: Why is bipolarity necessary?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10023/wittgenstein-why-is-bipolarity-necessary)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does Samir Okasha mean in this quote about converting invalid to valid argument?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9799/what-does-samir-okasha-mean-in-this-quote-about-converting-invalid-to-valid-argu)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Recommendations for reading in Constructive Mathematics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10086/recommendations-for-reading-in-constructive-mathematics)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Does Nietzsche's Free Death apply to God?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/does-nietzsches-free-death-apply-to-god)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How do you tell what are human rights?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-do-you-tell-what-are-human-rights)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is mathematics discovered through introspection?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9910/is-mathematics-discovered-through-introspection)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Assuming a mind could be uploaded, how would we know if it worked?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10110/assuming-a-mind-could-be-uploaded-how-would-we-know-if-it-worked)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Does Hegel's Schematization of Art Still Work?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9895/does-hegels-schematization-of-art-still-work)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Does this reduction to the absurd bastardize the technique?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/does-this-reduction-to-the-absurd-bastardize-the-technique)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Can time be spoken about in philosophy as something separate from everything else?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9794/can-time-be-spoken-about-in-philosophy-as-something-separate-from-everything-els)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Comment: The Wittgenstein question should read "Why is Bivalence Necessary?" Bivalence is the property of being either true or false, bipolarity sounds like a mental disorder.